# Async testing React Navigation 5 in Jest: NavigationContainer causes console error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I'm using `react-native-testing-library` and after upgrading `react-navigation` from 4 to 5, I followed these instructions: https://callstack.github.io/react-native-testing-library/docs/react-navigation to upgrade most of my test suite.

So far so good. The crux here is basically to wrap your tests in a `NavigationContainer` so my components have access to those hooks that previously came from `react-navigation-hooks`.

This works fine when my tests are synchronous, but as soon as I add the `async` keyword to the test function, I get the following warning:

```
console.error
    Warning: An update to ForwardRef(NavigationContainer) inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).

    When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):

    act(() => {
      /* fire events that update state */
    });
    /* assert on the output */

    This ensures that you're testing the behavior the user would see in the browser. Learn more at https://reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html#act
        in ForwardRef(NavigationContainer)
```

There are plenty of tests that I run synchronously and which succeed. But in some components, I do run some async logic to get the desired result.

From what I understand, I should wrap any async code in an `act` call. However, even in this case, I can't get rid of this error.

---

I went ahead to try and narrow down the issue. Now, all I do is render the wrapped component like this:

```
test('a simple test', async () => {
  const component = (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <AppNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );

  const {queryByText} = render(component);
  expect(queryByText('test')).toBeNull();
});
```

And I'm still running into the same issue. Be aware that the actual test succeeds, only that I'm still getting this console error.

Next, I tried to wrap the `render` call in `act` and `waitForElement`, because that's what I'm supposed to do when running async logic. But it seems that the async code here is executed *after* the rendering happens.

So I went on to investigate which part of `NavigationContainer` is responsible for firing the async logic responsible for the error, and it seems that this bit of code (line 49-51) does something interesting:

```
const [isReady, initialState = rest.initialState] = useThenable(
  getInitialState
);
```

`getInitialState` is the result of destructuring the return value of the `useLinking` call some lines before (43-47). Without going into further detail, `getInitialState` is wrapped inside a promise in there, so it becomes "thenable".

Now, if I uncomment the `useThenable`, the console error goes away. But obviously that's not something I can easily achieve from outside this file. So I'm a bit stuck here because I don't know how to write my test code in an async way without running into this error all the time, and I don't feel like ignoring or suppressing it is a good idea either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My recommendation after calling `render` from `react-native-testing-library` for components that do async work, `useEffect` (acting as `componentDidMount`), changing state, etc:

```js
await act(async () => {})
```

Or even:

```js
await act(async () => await flushMicrotasksQueue())
```

If you have some timeouts around.

Comment: Thanks, adding `await act(async () => {})` right after the render call helped me get rid of the error.

Comment: This works, but strangely I now get this warning:
`Warning: You called act(async () => ...) without await.`
Despite what the warning says, I've definitely waited the act()

Answer (score 2):

The instance of Test Renderer has the unmount() method that unmount the in-memory tree, triggering the appropriate lifecycle events. At the end of your test add:

```
component.unmount()
```

You can get more information at https://reactjs.org/docs/test-renderer.html#testrendererunmount.

Comment: Exactly at which line do we need to add this? After `act` or `create` or `expect`?

Answer (score 0):

I was only able to get this button go away by putting the `expect` and `render` calls in the same function.  Returning the render result from a shared function caused the `ForwardRef` error.  Very strange but I narrowed it down to this.

I'm also using a call to this `wait()` function after render, which lets Apollo run a GraphQL query too:

```
export async function wait(ms = 0): Promise<void> {
  return await act(async () => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
  });
}
```